# Pandas dataframe to multikey dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to transform df like this into the dictionary with multiple nested keys.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

columns = ['country', 'city', 'from_date', 'to_date', 'sales']
data = [['UK', 'London', datetime.date(2021, 8, 26), datetime.date(2099, 5,5), 2500], ['Mexico', 'Mexico City', datetime.date(2011, 3,3), datetime.date(2012, 4, 5), 5670], ['Mexico', 'Mexico City', datetime.date(2014, 3,3), datetime.date(2017, 4, 5), 5680]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
df
  country         city from_date     to_date  sales
0      UK       London 2021-08-26  2099-05-05   2500
1  Mexico  Mexico City 2011-03-03  2012-04-05   5670
2  Mexico  Mexico City 2014-03-03  2017-04-05   5680
```

Result # 1 I'm looking for:

```
{'Mexico': 
   {'Mexico City':
      [
         {'from_date: 2011-03-03, 'to_date:  2012-04-05, 'sales': 5670},
         {'from_date: 2014-03-03, 'to_date:  2017-04-05, 'sales': 5680}
      ]},
'UK': 
     {'London':
       [
         {'from_date: 2021-08-26, 'to_date:  2099-05-05, 'sales': 2500}
      ]},
}
```

Or Result #2:

```
{'Mexico': 
   {'Mexico City':
      {2011-03-03: 5670,  # from_date: sales
      2014-03-03: 5680}   # from_date: sales
   },
'UK': 
     {'London':
       {2021-08-26: 2500}   # from_date: sales
      },
}
```

I don't know how to get result #1, as for result #2 I've tried this:

```
df.groupby(['country', 'city', 'from_date'])['sales'].apply(float).to_dict()
{('Mexico', 'Mexico City', Timestamp('2011-03-03 00:00:00')): 5670.0, ('Mexico', 'Mexico City', Timestamp('2014-03-03 00:00:00')): 5670.0, ('UK', 'London', Timestamp('2021-08-26 00:00:00')): 2500.0}
```

BUT I need to be able to get `from_date` as a separate key because I will be using it to compare to another date.
Ideally, I'd like to learn how to get both results but any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your example code is missing `import datetime` and not sure what that `import dataframe` is?

Comment: The structure from "Result #2" does not seem to be possible, in the first pace. If you want to have multiple dicts without a key, you would have to put them inside an array: `[{2011-03-03: 5670}, {2014-03-03: 5680}]`; also the innermost dicts in the format `{2011-03-03: 5670}` seem to be a misuse of dicts. "Result #1" seems doable, though.

Comment: @JonClements it was simple typo - fixed to import datetime :)

Comment: @Haroldo_OK you're right - I've put them as dict.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex Series` by lambda function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
df['from_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['from_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df['to_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['to_date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

f = lambda x: x.to_dict('records')
s = df.groupby(['country', 'city'])[['from_date','to_date','sales']].apply(f)


d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)

{
    'Mexico': {
        'Mexico City': [{
                'from_date': '2011-03-03',
                'to_date': '2012-04-05',
                'sales': 5670
            },
            {
                'from_date': '2014-03-03',
                'to_date': '2017-04-05',
                'sales': 5680
            }
        ]
    },
    'UK': {
        'London': [{
            'from_date': '2021-08-26',
            'to_date': '2099-05-05',
            'sales': 2500
        }]
    }
}
```

For second is changed lambda function only:

```
f = lambda x: x.set_index('from_date')['sales'].to_dict()
s2 = df.groupby(['country', 'city']).apply(f)
print (s2)
country  city       
Mexico   Mexico City    {'2011-03-03': 5670, '2014-03-03': 5680}
UK       London                             {'2021-08-26': 2500}
dtype: object

d2 = {level: s2.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s2.index.levels[0]}
print (d2)
{'Mexico': {'Mexico City': {'2011-03-03': 5670, '2014-03-03': 5680}}, 
 'UK': {'London': {'2021-08-26': 2500}}}
```

Comment: many thanks @jezrael ! this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: and there was me just playing around with: `{k[0]: {k[1]: g.loc[:, 'from_date':].to_dict('records')} for k, g in df.groupby(['country', 'city'])}` :p